# Construcción de sentencia mysqli php para arreglos multidimensionales de 4 niveles

Tags: php, mysqli, array

Tengo una base de datos con sólo tres campos: id, afiliado, padrino.

1. Cada padrino tiene hasta 10 afiliados. (Primer Nivel)
2. Cada afiliado tiene hasta 10 sub-afiliados. (Segundo Nivel)
3. Cada sub-afiliado tiene hasta 10 sub-sub-afiliados. (Tercer Nivel)
4. Cada sub-sub-afiliado tiene hasta 10 afiliados finales. (Cuarto Nivel Final)

Se muestra un ejemplo de la base de datos:

```
id, IDPadrino, IDAfiliado
0,A001,A123
1,A001,A456
2,A456,A789
3,A456,A987
4,A456,A654
5,A789,A101
6,A101,A258, etc..
```

Cuando se registra una nueva persona, automáticamente se registra como su padrino al afiliado que lo recomendó. Todo esto ya está funcionando.

Ando en busca de una sentencia mysqli que me permita extraer de esa base de datos, en arreglos multidimensionales, todos los afiliados del nivel 1 hasta el 4, a partir del número de un sólo afiliado.

En el código que pongo, yo logro extraer el primero y segundo nivel de afiliados de esa base de datos, pero no puedo sacar el tercer y cuarto nivel. ¿Me ayudan por favor?

```
$numero_afiliado = ($_POST['numeroafiliado']);
    #Extraer todas las filas primer nivel
    $consulta = "SELECT IDAfiliado FROM DatosAfiliados WHERE IDPadrino='$numero_afiliado'";
    $resultado = $conexion -> query($consulta);
    while($fila = $resultado -> fetch_array())
    {
        $datosnivel1[] = $fila["IDAfiliado"];
    }
    $cuentaregistrosdatosnivel1 = count($datosnivel1);
    echo "El afiliado no. $numero_afiliado tiene $cuentaregistrosdatosnivel1 afiliados en este primer nivel.<br>";
        print_r($datosnivel1);
        echo "<br>Empiezo a buscar el nivel 2:<br>";
    for($i = 0; $i < count($datosnivel1); ++$i)
    {
            $consulta = "SELECT IDAfiliado FROM DatosAfiliados WHERE IDPadrino=$datosnivel1[$i]";
            $resultado = $conexion -> query($consulta);
            while($fila = $resultado -> fetch_array())
            {
                $datosnivel2[$i][] = $fila["IDAfiliado"];
            }
            echo "En este segundo nivel, si acaso existen, para el afiliado " . $datosnivel1[$i] . " tenemos " . count($datosnivel2[$i]) . " subafiliados.<br>";
            $cantidaddatosdentrodelarreglo[$i] = count($datosnivel2[$i]);

            print_r($datosnivel2[$i]);

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Entiendo que numero_afiliado es el código del padrino del cual quieres sacar sus afiliados de nivel X.

Para ello debes unir varias veces la misma tabla para buscar los siguientes niveles:

## Nivel 3

```
SELECT subafiliados.IDAfiliado
  FROM DatosAfiliados as afiliados
  INNER JOIN DatosAfiliados as subafiliados on (subafiliados.IDPadrino = afiliados.IDAfiliado)
  WHERE afiliados.IDPadrino='$numero_afiliado'
```

## Level 4

```
SELECT subsubafiliados.IDAfiliado
  FROM DatosAfiliados as afiliados
  INNER JOIN DatosAfiliados as subafiliados on (subafiliados.IDPadrino = afiliados.IDAfiliado)
  INNER JOIN DatosAfiliados as subsubafiliados on (subsubafiliados.IDPadrino = subafiliados.IDAfiliado)
  WHERE afiliados.IDPadrino='$numero_afiliado'
```

Como ves puedes añadir más niveles si quieres simplemente añadiendo un nuevo INNER JOIN ;-)